# Gram Matrix and Covariance Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

We usually seen matrices like $X^\top X$ and $XX^\top$. Sometimes we call them covariance matrices and sometimes we call them Gram matrices. Can anyone help me get clear about the distinctions between those two?

Comment: $XX^T$ represents the similarity matrix, e.g., if $X$ is row normalized, each entry represents pairwise cosine similarity. $X^TX$ is the covariance matrix if we have $X$ is mean-normalized (has 0 mean columns), since $\Sigma=E[X^TX]$, when we have $E[X]=0$. Both matrices have same eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of one matrix can be obtained from the other one's by simple linear transformation.

Comment: thanks for the note. how about Gram matrices? what are they?